# GMail filter that Skips the Inbox for ALL new messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to create a Gmail filter that Skips the Inbox for ALL new messages.

It works well for new incoming messages. However, when there is a conversation (thread) in the inbox, if the new incoming message is related to this conversation, it does not skip the inbox (thus triggering a notification).

I confirm that the option below is deactivated:
[image]

Is there any way to create a filter that works in all cases? My goal is to avoid the notification.

Comment: Is this programming related or are you trying to do this in the gmail web application?   This sounds like it may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is programming-related as I am doing everything with the GMail API. I am open to any solution involving calls to GMail API.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Have you checked if those old threads have the `INBOX` tag? That could be the trigger for the notification.